# Return to root view in IOS

Tags: ios, root, viewcontroller

To some this may sound like a daft question. I've searched around, and found little, mostly because I cannot find the appropriate search terms.

Here what I want to do is:

The application begins at view A.

View A launches view B, and view B launches view C.

Is their a way for view C to return directly back to A without dismissing itself and thus exposing B. For example a main menu button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered a solution to my problem. Its a bit dirty, (and I''ll probably get shot down in flames for it) but works very well under tests and is very quick to implement. Here's how I did it.

In my app I have a Singleton class called **GlobalVars** (I use this for storing various global settings). This class holds a boolean called **home_pressed** and associated accessors (via synthesise). You could also store this value in the application delegate if you wish.

In every view controller with a main menu button, I wire the button to the **homePressed** IBAction method as follows. First setting the global **homePressed** boolean to **YES**, then dismissing the view controller in the usual way, but with **NO** animation.

```
-(IBAction) homePressed: (id) sender
{
   [GlobalVars _instance].homePressed = YES;
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO];
}//end homePressed
```

In every view controller except the main menu I implement the **viewDidAppear** method (which gets called when a view re-appears) as follows.

```
-(void) viewDidAppear: (Bool) animated
{
   if ([GlobalVars _instance].homePressed == YES)
   {
      [self dismissModalViewController: NO];
   }
   else
   {
      //put normal view did appear code here/
   }

}//end viewDidAppead
```

In the **mainMenu** view controller which is the **root** of the app, I set the global **homePressed** boolean to **NO** in its view did appear method as follows

```
-(void) viewDidAppear: (Bool) animated
{
   if ([GlobalVars _instance].homePressed == YES)
   {
      [GlobalVars _instance].homePressed == NO;
   }
   else
   {
      //put normal view did appear code here/
   }

}//end viewDidAppear
```

There, this enables me to go back to the root main menu of my app from any view further down the chain.

I was hoping to avoid this method, but its better than re-implementing my app which is what I'd have to do if I wanted use the UINavigationController solution.

Simple, took me 10 minutes to code in my 9 view app. :)

One final question I do have, would my solution be OK with the HIG?

Answer (score 11):

You can call `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` if you have a UINavigationController.  If you specify `NO` to animate it, then it will just jump back to the root without showing B first.

Comment: I'm trying [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated: NO]; in the IBAction event stub fired by the main menu button. It appears to have no effect but gets executed without raising an error.

Comment: OK, first question do you have a UINavigationController and push your views (via their own view controllers) onto the stack?  Every view controller has a navigationController property, but it might be set to nil.

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html to see if this is the effect you are trying to reproduce.

Comment: Whe I launch views I'm using [self presentModalViewController: exportMenu animated: YES]. It appears that that self.navigation controller is null.

Comment: OK, so you are presenting modal view controllers on top of other modal view controllers, is that right?  It would be helpful if you could explain in a little more detail the effect you are trying to create so I can advise you better.

Comment: It seems odd to me that this navigation controller is required.This kind of functionality should come as standard in any IOS view. As there is a stack in memory, one would expect to able to drop to any position in that stack, which would then dismiss all proceeding views from the position chosen.

Comment: I just want to be able to return to the first view in a stack which is the applications main menu. I would like all my views to have a "Main Menu" button to facilitate this.

Comment: Oh and Yes I am presenting modal view controllers on top of each other.

Comment: iOS views are generally managed by a view controller and collections (or stacks) of view controllers are managed by one of the view controller container classes, like a UITabBarController or UINavigationController, and this is what they are designed for.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I invented another solution. I have been able to answer my question rather well, I would love to share the solution with you because I believe it's valuable for others to read and quite inventive. However, this stifling rule "Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours"  prevents me from doing so,  sorry, maybe later eh. :(

Comment: Sure, no problem sounds intriguing.