# PushViewController iOS

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller

I have three view controllers. `MainViewController`, `secondViewController`, `thirdViewController`. I would like to know once I click on `done` button on the `thirdViewcontroller`,

How could I go directly yo `MainViewController` instead of going back `secondViewController` and then `MainViewcontroller` by using `pushViewController`?

Comment: This could be quickly resolved by reading the documentation. It is a good habit to build and will help you resolve issues faster. Hope this helps!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return to root view in IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035320/return-to-root-view-in-ios)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your using a navigation controller, you can pop to root by calling:

```
[[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This will bring you back to your MainViewController.

Comment: superrr , thanks a lot appreciated! tested and works flawlessly