# Back to RootViewController from Modal View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

From Home view - my RootViewController - I open up 2 ViewControllers one after another as user progresses in navigation hierarchy like so:

1) SecondViewController is pushed by button connected in my Storyboard

2) ThirdViewController is presented modally

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextViewController" sender:nil];
```

So, the picture is:  RootViewController -> SecondViewController -> ThirdViewController

Now in my ThirdViewController I want to have a button to go back 2 times to my RootViewController, i.e. go home. But this does not work:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Only this guy goes back once to SecondViewController

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

How can I remove both modal and pushed view controllers at the same time?

Comment: I think what you want to do is in your thirdViewController: [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO]; [self.presentingViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];, excuse the poor typing I'm on a mobile

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return to root view in IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035320/return-to-root-view-in-ios)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had a similar situation, where I had a number of view controllers pushed onto the navigation controller stack, and then the last view was presented modally. On the modal screen, I have a Cancel button that goes back to the root view controller.

In the modal view controller, I have an action that is triggered when the Cancel button is tapped:

```
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate modalViewControllerDidCancel];
}
```

In the header of this modal view controller, I declare a protocol:

```
@protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate
- (void)modalViewControllerDidCancel;
@end
```

And then the last view controller in the navigation stack (the one that presented the modal view) should implement the `ModalViewControllerDelegate` protocol:

```
- (void)modalViewControllerDidCancel
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This method above is the important part. It gets the presenting view controller to dismiss the modal view, and then it pops back to the root view controller. Note that I pass `NO` to dismissViewControllerAnimated: and `YES` to popToRootViewControllerAnimated: to get a smoother animation from modal view to root view.

Comment: I am testing your solution. Delegate way is more complicated but maybe worth trying.

Comment: Your answer helped me. I only had to do it through post notification instead of delegate

Comment: And lastly the first line was [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

Comment: @Vad I'm glad you got it working. The dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: method has been deprecated in iOS 6.0. The recommended method to use now is dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:, [see doco here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW30).

Comment: Thx, I spend a lot of time to get run a simular problem. Nothing worked !! But this simple solution solved the Problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same requirement but was using custom segues between the view controllers. I came across with the concept of "Unwind Segue" which I think came with iOS6. If you are targeting iOS6 and above these links might help:
[What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-to-use-them)
http://chrisrisner.com/Unwinding-with-iOS-and-Storyboards
Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know about it but have to support iOS5 :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your AppDelegate is called AppDelegate, then you can do the following which will reset the rootviewcontroller for the app window as the view RootViewController

```
AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
RootViewController *rootView = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
[appDel.window setRootViewController:rootView];
```