# Transitions between view controllers

Tags: ios, transition, viewcontroller

I have this situation in iOS: View A present view B, from view B go to view C. From view C, if go back, go back to view A.

I dont wanna use navigation controller. Which way the the best to do it? Right now I am doing like this:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.window.rootViewController.view
                    toView:viewController.view
                  duration:0.5f
                   options:transition
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    //[viewController viewWillAppear:NO];
                    if(self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController){
                        [self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

                        }];
                    }
                    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
                }];
```

But when I try to use same method to go back, it shows the middle view which is view B. Any better solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return to root view in IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035320/return-to-root-view-in-ios).

Comment: A piece of suggestion..dude,u should use navigation controller.if you have any issue with navigation bar,u can hide it.That is the best approach and manages memory very well